# Can't add code to comment

Tags: support, comments, markdown, code-formatting, inline-code

I am trying to add code to my comment using inline `code in backticks`, but it doesn't work for the below path:

`\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftE‌​dge_xxxx\AC\#!001\Mi‌​crosoftEdge\Cache\`

Comment: ``\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftE‌​dge_xxxx\AC\#!001\Mi‌​crosoftEdge\Cache\``

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use double backticks if the code ends in a backslash.

```
``\Users\user_name\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.MicrosoftE‌​dge_xxxx\AC\#!001\Mi‌​crosoftEdge\Cache\``
```